# Detect double tap on ipad or iphone screen using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, events

I'd like to detect if a user has double tapped on an ipad or iphone.

Does a javascript-event exist which would provide this functionality?

Answer (score 42):

This could be used for a double tap or a double click. In pure javascript:

```
var mylatesttap;
function doubletap() {

   var now = new Date().getTime();
   var timesince = now - mylatesttap;
   if((timesince < 600) && (timesince > 0)){

    // double tap   

   }else{
            // too much time to be a doubletap
         }

   mylatesttap = new Date().getTime();

}
```

Comment: interesting solution. I wonder which is more efficient, the set/clear timeout or this.

Comment: this code does not detect single tap! it only detects double tap

Comment: @raypixar: this is exactly what Jorge said and what the asker wanted

Comment: @Thariama Double tap detection without Single tap detection has no meaning. Both of them should be detected.

Comment: quick suggestion: add `if (mylatesttap === undefined) { mylatesttap = new Date().getTime(); }` at the beginning of the function. You also might want to throw in a `setTimeout(singleTap, doubleTapTimeout + 10)` where doubleTapTimeout would be the timeout in ms (in the example in answer this would be `600`) and `singleTap` is a function that checks if the double tap was implemented (this would require another "global" variable under the window variable (such that if the double tap is successful -- where you have the `// double tap` comment -- it would have `true` stored into it). cheers & thanks

Comment: @raypixar: basically the 'else' part of the condition is the single tap

Comment: This needs changes if single tap is to be detected as well.

Answer (score 33):

One basic idea is to do it like this:

1. In order to create a double-tap (or double click) event you need to create code on the `onClick` event.
2. The reason you most likely want double-tap/click is because you already have something attached to the `onClick` event and need a different gesture on the same element.
3. This means that your `onClick` event should only launch the `onClick` event after a `setTimeout()` is acknowledged.
4. So the basic code would launch the function attached to the `onClick` event using a `setTimeout()` command. The first click says "Start timer + run function using `setTimeout()` after say..500 milliseconds. The second time you clicked, you would check to see if the second click was inside a specific time frame in order to count as a double tap. So if the End time was less than 500 milliseconds, you would cancel the `setTimeout()` using `clearTimeout()` and then launch a completely different function (the function you wanted to launch for double tab/click)
5. Stopping default action? - Probably somthing like `stopPropagation()` or `cancelBubble()` would do the trick. Honestly, I don't know but that's where I'd start researching.

Answer (score 29):

### Detect Double Tap

try the following snippet on a touch device

`event.preventDefault()` will disable **double tap zoom** on `div#double-tap`

```js
document.getElementById("double-tap").addEventListener("touchstart", tapHandler);

var tapedTwice = false;

function tapHandler(event) {
    if(!tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = true;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = false; }, 300 );
        return false;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    //action on double tap goes below
    alert('You tapped me Twice !!!');
 }
```

```css
div#double-tap {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;  
}
```

```html
<div id="double-tap">Double Tap Me !!!</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need add event1.pageX - event0.pageX < xx to avoid two fingers touch trigger double tap.

Answer (score 23):

I created this one in JavaScript and it seems to work well. (I tested it on my iPad 2.)
It is basically the code for what is said above.

```
var clickTimer = null;

function touchStart() {
    if (clickTimer == null) {
        clickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            clickTimer = null;
            alert("single");

        }, 500)
    } else {
        clearTimeout(clickTimer);
        clickTimer = null;
        alert("double");

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'll have a try next time!

Comment: Yeah currently this solution still working. I tried at Ipad Air 2.Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I found this solution on Stackoverflow somewhere but forgot what exact post. It works for a doubleclick on a browser and double tap on iPhone.

I use `'touchend click'` to detect the double click on both browser and iPhone. To implement just on iPhone, remove the click.

```
var timeout;
var lastTap = 0;

$('element').on('touchend click',function(e){
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var tapLength = currentTime - lastTap;        

    e.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    if(tapLength < 500 && tapLength > 0){

        //Double Tap/Click

    }else{

        //Single Tap/Click

        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            //Single Tap/Click code here

            clearTimeout(timeout); 
        }, 500);
    }
    lastTap = currentTime;
});
```

Comment: I added a test to check if the scroll position of the 1st and 2nd tap are the same to ignore two taps where there is a scroll change between them.  Otherwise this works great.

Answer (score 7):

Double tap on an iPad is tricky because the browser, by default, absorbs this event as a "zoom" event, as seen here:

[image: Doubletap - Apple API docs]

However, if you cancel the default behavior, you can grab the doubletap yourself. Here's an example of a plugin that does this for you-- the [jQuery doubletap plugin](http://www.sanraul.com/2010/08/01/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/).

Comment: that plugin works very bad with multitouch gestures on the selector

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault();` to disable the default zoom event. I recommend doing this within the specific element you want to double click on rather than the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

Might be late (Actually yup it's damn late), but the pure and easy JS solution for those lurking in the future:

```
var tapped="";
function dbtapper(elem=false,arg1, arg2, arg3, timer=1400){
    if(tapped==""){
        //Here is single tap

        tapped = setTimeout(function(){tapclean()}, timer)
        lastclick = elem;
        //variable lastclick is to prevent double clicking from happen
        //when clicking different object with double-click listener.

    } else if(lastclick==elem){
        //Here is double tap, if you want more (triple&beyond),
        //add doubletap/tripletap checker variable into tapclean().
        //and set it to true here!, example included.
        //you could also add more setTimeout to var-tapped so user will
        //have more time to do triple&up taps.

        tapclean();
        //doubletapped=true;
        mypersonalfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    } else {
        tapped = setTimeout(function(){tapclean()}, timer);
        lastclick = elem;
}
}
function tapclean(){
    clearTimeout(tapped);
    tapped="";
    //doubletapper=false;
}
```

With this you can easily make single tap event, double, triple, fourth,... to infinity and beyond!
Notice: to use element checking, call the function like:
`dbtapper(YOURELEMENT), ie: <span onclick="dbtapper(this)">Click Me</span>`

It's not forced tho, you can use it without just fine (`dbtapper()`), but if you need to pass argument into the function make sure you type false for the first argument if you doesn't point it to the element.

```
Without element pointer: dbtapper(false,yourarguments)
With element pointer: dbtapper(document.getElement*******,yourarguments)
Alternatively, you can use an unique elem arg for each element:
                    dbtapper('omega',yourarg) or dbtapper(69,yourarg)
Though this is not recommended if you have a huge amount of double tapping elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

technoweenie's jquery.doubletap does
and this link: [jQuery mobile events finally launched](http://ben-major.co.uk/2012/05/jquery-mobile-events-finally-launched/)
seems to be able to solve the task ...

Comment: Please include the essential answer from the link, in addition to just posting the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [jquery.finger](https://github.com/ngryman/jquery.finger) which supports **delegated events**.

Comment: When voting down, please explain why. jquery.finger handles doubletap, which answers the question.

Comment: The downvote reason is clearly explained in the [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag: _"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."_ -- with that in mind, this is not considered a good answer, even though it is most definitely a working solution if someone decides to go with a 60KB library (+plugin) for something that can be done with at most 10 lines of code, including comments. Additionally, link-only answers are discouraged (as the link can go bad), especially when no code is included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

based on latest jquery docs, double tap implementation

https://gist.github.com/attenzione/7098476