# jQuery slideUp not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile

I have a Wordpress site running Flatsome theme where there are some pages with sidebars created using [Custom Sidebar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/) which are not showing up on a menu hover. I have try to fix that glitch using jQuery code below

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".widget_nav_menu .menu-item-has-children").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery('ul.sub-menu', this).slideDown('medium');
        }, 

        function () {
                jQuery('ul.sub-menu', this).slideUp('medium');
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

which works fine on any computer browser but not on mobile devices (iPhone and iPad) and I have no clue what can cause that.

Comment: Mobile devices? like all of them? please specify as I know it works on some ;)

Comment: Because mobile devices don't support hover.

Comment: @COOOL iPhone and iPad (added to the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't **hover** on mobile.

```
jQuery(".widget_nav_menu .menu-item-has-children").hover( // change
```

Trigger above differently on Mobile, such as using **[double tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825144/detect-double-tap-on-ipad-or-iphone-screen-using-javascript).** [hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-jquery)

..or [**mousedown**](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) / **[mouse leave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**.

---

**sample mobile friendly alteration**: 
(untested but hopeflly you get the idea, it's not the `.slideDown` that is failing, it's the `.hover`)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".widget_nav_menu .menu-item-has-children").mouseout(function(){
        function () {
            jQuery('ul.sub-menu', this).slideDown('medium');
        }, 

        function () {
                jQuery('ul.sub-menu', this).slideUp('medium');
        }
    );

});
```

Your second part question may be -- how to maintain `.hover` trigger on **desktop** and trigger a mobile one as I'm suggesting on *only* **mobile**.

Comment: You can't test hover on mobile, think about it

Comment: It looks like something wrong is there with a syntax (function after mouseout)