# html select ondblclick mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

When I double click a option, it will execute javascript function.
Testing on iphone safari, it just pops out a select menu list.

Can't execute javascript function.

How to I fix this?

```
<select name="EmployeeID" size="5" class="bar" id="EmployeeID" style="width:80%" 
        scrolling="yes" 
        ondblclick="insertOption('FlowGo',this.options[this.selectedIndex].text,this.opt‌​ions[this.selectedIndex].value);putValue('FlowGo')"
>
    <option value="0">----choose----</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O, can you paste your code?

Comment: thanks.
it just like this below:
`<select  name="EmployeeID" size="5" class="bar" id="EmployeeID" style="width:80%" scrolling="yes" ondblclick="insertOption('FlowGo',this.options[this.selectedIndex].text,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);putValue('FlowGo')">
        <option value="0">----choose----</option>
      </select>`

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code there, instead of in a comment.  That way you can format it and people can read it more easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect double tap on ipad or iphone screen using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825144/detect-double-tap-on-ipad-or-iphone-screen-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Click events are handled differently on tablets and phones because they are considered "tap" events. jQuery, if I remember correctly, treats them the same as far as single clicks, but double tap events are not included.

You may need to use jQuery plus a plugin called [doubletap.js](https://gist.github.com/attenzione/7098476).