# Zoom issue in iPhone for iOS 10

Tags: iphone, zooming, viewport, meta, ios10

Is there any viewport meta tag available for iOS 10 ?

I am facing zoom issue on my iPhone. I am using `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">` and also `user-scalable=no` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this meta is not taken into account anymore with iOS 10 RC.
Users are able to zoom in/out freely even when this meta.

I'm looking for a clean solution for that.

See [disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Answer (score 0):

fyi, It still works for home screen app

Comment: I had try above meta tag but still not working in any screen if it is working on  your home screen app can i have example!

Comment: @Rushi `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0">` here you go

Comment: Thanks @Thinh, I already tried this viewport meta, but it is not working in ios 10. Please let me know if any other solution is there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly heavy GIS web-app that crashes when iOS devices with 1 Gigabyte of RAM try to zoom. After much experimentation, this is what works for me. Hope it helps. If anyone has any suggestions to improve this, then by all means enlighten us all! :)

```
// CSS (This prevents zoom on input)
input {
    font-size: 16px!important;
}

// JavaScript (I use jQuery). This prevents pinch zoom.
var numTouches = 0;
$('body').on('touchmove', function(event){
    numTouches = event.originalEvent.touches.length;
    if(numTouches > 1){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

// And this prevents double tap zoom
var mylatesttap = new Date().getTime();
$('body').on('touchstart', function(event){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timesince = now - mylatesttap;
    if((timesince < 500) && (timesince > 0)){
        // double tap
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //alert('You tapped me Twice !!!');
    }else{
        // too much time to be a doubletap
    }

    mylatesttap = new Date().getTime();
});
```

This code was built upon samples from this post: 
[Detect double tap on ipad or iphone screen using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825144/detect-double-tap-on-ipad-or-iphone-screen-using-javascript/19515695#19515695)

Comment: Just a note, if you un-comment the alert for the double tap zoom blocker, you'll see the alert, but it will disrupt the function somehow and iOS Safari 10.x will still zoom.