# Disable click and enable double click on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have a menu dropdown:

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that on mobile, you cannot see submenu cause of when you click it redirects you instantly.

So I'd like trigger hover on tap and trigger to redirect on double tap on mobile devices.

I've tryed this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $(".navbar a").on('doubletap', function () {
    window.location = this.href;
    console.log('d');
  });
  $(".navbar a").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

But now the preventDefault() function override the doubletap function.

I need some help, there is no topic that could help me

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbar, .navbar ul {
    background:#2D7D9A;
    list-style: none;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    z-index:2;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li {
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.navbar li ul {
    background:#0099BC;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.navbar li ul li ul {
    background:#038387;
    width:100%;
    /* left:5%; */
    top:45px;
}
.navbar li a {
    color:#bfffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #bfffff;
}
.navbar li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
.navbar li ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/fsc76qyt/3/

Comment: use this https://jsfiddle.net/fsc76qyt/5/

Comment: Almost! On desktop it works but on mobile not. If I double click it zoom/unzoom but it never trigger the link.

Comment: Maybe this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825144/detect-double-tap-on-ipad-or-iphone-screen-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can try this combination of timedout

```js
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;
$(".navbar a").on("click", function(e){

        clicks++;  //count clicks

        if(clicks === 1) {
        e.preventDefault();

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                alert("Single Click");  //perform single-click action    
                clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
        
            }, DELAY);

        } else {

            clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
            alert("Double Click");  //perform double-click action
            clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
        }

    })
    .on("dblclick", function(e){
        window.location = this.href;
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbar, .navbar ul {
    background:#2D7D9A;
    list-style: none;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    z-index:2;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li {
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.navbar li ul {
    background:#0099BC;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.navbar li ul li ul {
    background:#038387;
    width:100%;
    /* left:5%; */
    top:45px;
}
.navbar li a {
    color:#bfffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 10px #bfffff;
}
.navbar li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
.navbar li ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are using the wrong way. first of all, you have to call this function on click then you can check the device width. check it out my code. Hope this code work for you. Thank You.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".navbar a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(this).dblclick(function (e) {
                window.location = this.href;
            });
        }
        else{
            window.location = this.href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It work! I'm not expert but my code is shorter. If someone can confirm that this code is better OK :) Thanks

Comment: @JuliaRopoulos I just showing you how you can use dblclick() function of jquery instead of using click function multiple times and I think it's better shorter code than yours.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Thanks everybody

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $(".navbar a").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
      window.location = this.href;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: this wont work properly, try clicking the "link" and hold for 1 second then click again "link". this will generate a double click and the page will redirect which is a wrong thing. So single click will convert to double click on click on it for two times